# How can I read an embedded assembly's version number from my executable?

Tags: c#

I have embedded a class library into my executable, by adding the following to my `.csproj` file.

```
  <Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)' == '.dll'">
        <LogicalName>%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.DestinationSubDirectory)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Filename)%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.Extension)</LogicalName>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Then, I load the assemblies programmatically by subscribing to the `AppDomain`'s `AssemblyResolve` event like so:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using xofz.Research.UI.Forms;

internal static class EntryPoint
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => loadEmbeddedAssembly(e.Name);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var bootstrapper = new FormsBootstrapper();
        new FormsAppBase(bootstrapper).Run(
            args);
    }

    private static Assembly loadEmbeddedAssembly(string name)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(name);
        if (name.EndsWith("Retargetable=Yes"))
        {
            return Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        }

        var container = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var path = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";

        using (var stream = container.GetManifestResourceStream(path))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return Assembly.Load(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

I then later in my app wish to read the embedded library's version number.  There is a `ReadCoreVersion()` method in the embedded library which attempts to do just that:

```
public virtual string ReadCoreVersion()
{
    var ea = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var vi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
        ea.Location);
    return vi.FileVersion;
}
```

However, when I attempted to call this method in my application's code, it threw an `ArgumentException: The path is not of a legal form.`

Is there any way to read an embedded assembly's version number?

Edit: after checking what the assembly's Location property consisted of, it was either null or empty.  How can I retrieve the location of the embedded assembly to retrieve its version, or do I have to flush the assembly out to disk first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the path you're passing to FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo is the correct format.

1. `Assembly.Location` [returns UNC path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` [expects a fully-qualified path.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

You'll either need to parse the string yourself to convert the path to the correct format, or use a built-in method that does the conversion for you.

[This page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm#GUID-A2A3F32B-D0AE-4F60-97A9-4DA8AF8DC00B) has a good breakdown on the different formats.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, `AssemblyName` was of great help here.  By modifying the `ReadCoreVersion()` method as follows, I was able to get it to display the embedded assembly's version information!

```
public virtual string ReadCoreVersion()
{
    var ea = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var an = new AssemblyName(ea.FullName);
    var v = an.Version;
    var versionBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    versionBuilder.Append(v.Major);
    versionBuilder.Append('.');
    versionBuilder.Append(v.Minor);
    versionBuilder.Append('.');
    versionBuilder.Append(v.Build);
    versionBuilder.Append('.');
    versionBuilder.Append(v.Revision);

    return versionBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Erm, this doesn't make sense.  How did you turn the *embedded* assembly into the executing assembly?

Comment: This code is actually inside of the embedded assembly, so it is, in fact, the executing assembly.  I use `GetEntryAssembly()` elsewhere for reading the version of the executable that the library is embedded into.

Comment: So the fact that it is embedded is completely irrelevant?

Comment: I had to use `AssemblyName` instead of `FileVersionInfo` to retrieve the version, that's all (since it wasn't flushed out to disk).